# Can I set breakpoint in a vim plugin script written in python?

Tags: vimscript, gvim, plugin-system

When a vim plugin is developed in a mixed script of vim script and python, can we set breakpoints and debug the python script. I tried to use [PDB](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) module, but vim is dead when it go to the `pdb.set_trace()`.

This post -- [Writing Vim plugin in Python](http://candidtim.github.io/vim/2017/08/11/write-vim-plugin-in-python.html) -- says "You can test and debug it outside Vim with whatever tools you typically use." But when the python script `import vim`, it cannot run outside Vim.

Note: I'm not asking how I can debug python code in vim like a python IDE. When I google for my question, all I got is to answer this different question. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find a way myself -- a python module [rpdb - remote debugger based on pdb](https://pypi.org/project/rpdb/).

It works for me.

1. Install using `pip install rpdb`
2. Set breakpoint with `rpdb.set_trace()` in plugin python script.
3. Try to active the plugin in vim. The vim will hang-up.
4. Use telnet to connect the vim process. `telnet localhost 4444`. It will be same as `pdb` to use.